# How do you display legends to zero decimal places when rounding fails?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

I can't create an MWE that is reproducible - this snapshot shows the output I am having trouble with.

[image: python output showing round returning unwanted decimal place]

I want to create labels for a plot legend (matplotlib) from this, but I need it to have zero decimal places.   Is there a more reliable form of `round` where you can force zero decimal places? Or, is there another way to get this working?  I don't want to create the list manually because the values I am plotting, and the functions that form them, will change.

I did try to assign the output of the `plot_R(thetaValues[40])*1e6` and then round that, but that didn't work either.  I also tried calling `round` twice in case that would work.  Interestingly, it is rounding to 0 decimal place (if you round to 1 the output is 160.3), it's just still printing the ".0"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to truncate the decimal, you could do:

```
decimal_round = round(plot_R(thetaValues[40])*1e6)
str_decimal = str(decimal_round)
if "." in str_decimal:
    decimal_round = int(str_decimal[:str_decimal.index(".")])
```

This finds the index of the decimal pt, slices the string representation to drop the decimal point and everything after, and then re-converts to an int.

Hope that helps, Happy Coding!